# Bootstrap - pause Carousel whithout a selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is to pause a bootstrap carousel. 
The general way to do it is via a jQuery selector as below:

```js
$('#carouselId').carousel('pause');
```

The problem is that sometimes another view must override the HTML that wraps the carousel, and the carousel element will no longer be on the page.
I noticed that the bootstrap interval JS continues running in the background, that might causes bad performance on my page, while unnecessary interval scripts are running.
I cannot pause it right before the UI element is going to be lost, because it happens in many cases, and there are more reasons.
Is there a way to stop bootstrap carousel script, when the UI element does not exist anymore?

I tried to hold the selector in an external variable in the Javascript file, and when need to pause the carousel to use it via that variable, as below:

```js
var carouselElem = $('#carouselId')
$(document).ready(function () {
     carouselElem .carousel();
});
```

and when need to pause:

```js
carouselElem.carousel('pause');
```

The variable still holds that reference to the missing element even after the element does not exist, but it does not help. I guess because the carousel `pause` function tries to access attributes of that element

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.carousel` selector

```
$('.carousel').carousel('pause')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('.carousel').carousel({
        pause: "true"
 });
```